# clojure Atom example codes: why the difference between let and def?

Tags: clojure, fibonacci

I read the doc https://clojure.org/reference/atoms and triy the codes about Fibonacci.

According the outputs below, in test 3, it takes as short as expected, using `def`. But in test 2,it take quite long time, using `let` instead of `def` to redefine fib. I wonder why `let` does NOT work as the same way as `def`?

```clj
(defn fib "original fib function" [n]
  (if (<= n 1)
    n
    (+ (fib (dec n)) (fib (- n 2)))))

(defn memorize [f]
  (let [mem (atom {})]
    (fn [& args]
      (if-let [e (find @mem args)]
        (val e)
        (let [ret (apply f args)]
          (swap! mem assoc args ret)
          ret)))))


(deftest test-memorize
  (testing "test memoize 1 - using fib"
    (println "test 1")
    (is (> (time (fib 35)) 0)))
  (testing "test memoize 2 - uising `(let [fib (memorize fib)])"
    (println "test 2")
    (let [fib (memorize fib)]
      (is (> (time (fib 35)) 0))))
  (testing "test memoize 3 - using `(def fib (memorize fib))"
    (println "test 3")
    (def fib (memorize fib))
    (is (> (time (fib 35)) 0)))
```

The outputs:

```sh
$ lein test :only app.model-test/test-memorize

lein test app.model-test
test 1
"Elapsed time: 1418.226187 msecs"
test 2
"Elapsed time: 1391.479784 msecs"
test 3
"Elapsed time: 0.215439 msecs"

Ran 1 tests containing 3 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
```

Answer (score 1):

*... why let does NOT work as the same way as def? ...* Because they serve different purposes.

- `def` creates, or **updates the value of**, a global var. It does not creat a local binding. (Compare to Racket where `define` is used at the top level to create global bindings and within functions for local bindings.) https://clojure.org/reference/special_forms#def
- `let` creates local bindings. https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/let

---

```
    (testing "test memoize 3 - using `(def fib (memorize fib))"
       (println "test 3")
       (def fib (memorize fib))
       (is (> (time (fib 35)) 0)))
```

Is redefining the **global** value of `fib` to be the value returned by `memorize fib`.  When the called with `(fib 35)` the memorize code will call what used to be named `fib`. That, original, fib calls, by name, `fib` which is now the memoized version, of fib to calculate fib 34. The calculation of fib 34 calls `fib` to calculate fib 33. So when `(fib 34)` returns and `(fib 35)` calls `(fib 33)`, but that value is cached already. The recursive implementation of fib creates a tree of computation. By redefining `fib` at the top to inject memoization the work, on the first call to `(fib 35)` is trimming the tree to a single branch.

For `let` to do the same thing would require Clojure to use dynamic scope instead of lexical scope.

---

Some ways to observe that `fib` is being redefined at the top. After running you tests, `(doc fib)` and see that your documentation string is not there. Because `fib` is no longer defined as the function you wrote.

Swap the order of the let and def tests. Then let will be getting the memoized fib.

If you define fib using `fn` as such:

```
(def fib (fn fib [n] 
     (if (<= n 1) 
         n (+ (fib (dec n))
         (fib (- n 2))))))
```

The call to fib inside will always go to itself, because it is using the local binding for `fib` from the `fn` form.

Answer (score 1):

As Shannon Severance already answered. `def` creates a global var. `let` creates a local binding.

**Which effect has this difference on your function?**

**Case 2 (let):**

You create a new function (a memoized version of fib) and bind it locally to the name fib. Then you call `fib`. `fib` calls `fib` recursively, but inside `defn fib ...` fib refers to the globally defined fib, which is not memoized. So effectively, there is no caching.

```
(testing "test memoize 2 - uising `(let [fib (memorize fib)])"
  (println "test 2")
  (let [fib (memorize fib)] ;-> new memoized version of fib, which is bound to the name fib
    (is (> (time (fib 35)) 0)))); but it is only available inside the let block
```

Effect on `defn fib`:

```
(defn fib "original fib function" [n]
  (if (<= n 1)
    n
    (+ (fib (dec n)) (fib (- n 2))))) ;-> calls fib, but fib refers to the globally defined fib, which is not memoized
```

**Case 3 (def):**

You create a memoized version of `fib`, then you globally redeclare `fib`'s value to be the new memoized version. You call `fib`. `Fib` calls itself, but now it refers to the new defined version, which is memoized.

```
(def fib (memorize fib)) ; -> you create a new global fn fib, which is memoized
(is (> (time (fib 35)) 0))
```

Effect on `defn fib`:

```
(defn fib "original fib function" [n]
  (if (<= n 1)
    n
    (+ (fib (dec n)) (fib (- n 2))))) ; -> now, the memoized version of fib is called
```